# How to modify the shape, font and color of tikzpicture labels? Here, I need white color circular labels beside every node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1.2cm, thick,
every node/.style = {rectangle, font = \Large\sffamily, black,
top color = green!90!white, bottom color = green!60!white,drop shadow,
text width = 8.4cm, align = center, minimum height = 2.3cm}]
\node[label={[fill=white, circle, yshift=2cm, font= \Large\sffamily, scale=0.4] right:22}] (SWGDAM) {\textbf{SWGDAM}\\Probabilistic Genotyping};
\coordinate [below = 2.5cm of SWGDAM] (Mitte);
\coordinate [below = 4.8cm of SWGDAM] (Unten);
\node (EDV)        [right = 10mm of Mitte, xshift=2cm]  {4.1};
\node (Verwaltung) [left = 10mm of Mitte, xshift=-2cm]  {4.2}; 
\coordinate [below = 0.5cm of EDV] (zoode);
\coordinate [below = 0.5cm of Verwaltung] (dire);
\node (Bau)        [below = of Verwaltung] {421};
\node (Logistik)   [below  = of Bau]        {4211};
\node (4212)   [below  = of Logistik]        {4212};
\node (4213)   [below  = of 4212]        {4213};
\node (Pflege)     [below = of EDV]        {411};
\node (Ausbildung) [right = of Pflege]     {412};
\node (413) [right = of Ausbildung]     {413};
\node (4121) [below = of Ausbildung]     {4121};
  \draw[line width=0.1cm, green!60!black]
(SWGDAM)    -- (Mitte) -- (Verwaltung)
% (EDV)   -- (Mitte) -- (Unten) -| (Logistik)
(EDV)   -- (Mitte)
 % (Unten) -| (Bau)
 % (Unten) -| (Pflege)
% (Unten) -| (Ausbildung);
(EDV)   -- (zoode)
(zoode) -| (Pflege)
(zoode)  -| (Ausbildung);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what are `dtklogos`? Is it a custom-package?

Comment: dtklogos.sty will be used for further development of this picture. Its not required at this stage - @runartrollet

Comment: when posting a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), try to remove everything which isn't essential to highlight your problem. The more you can remove, the better. People seeing this question later could more easily be helped that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want here, there really isn't too much information. Also, there was a lot of code which could be simplified. I am sure this could be solved a lot better than this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1.2cm, thick,
every node/.style = {rectangle, font = \Large\sffamily, black,
top color = green!90!white, bottom color = green!60!white,drop shadow,
text width = 8.4cm, align = center, minimum height = 2.3cm}]
\node[label={[fill=white, top color=white, bottom color=white, circle, yshift=2cm, text width=2cm, minimum height=0cm] right:{\Large\sffamily22}}] (SWGDAM) {\textbf{SWGDAM}\\Probabilistic Genotyping};
\coordinate [below = 2.5cm of SWGDAM] (Mitte);
\coordinate [below = 4.8cm of SWGDAM] (Unten);
\node (EDV)        [right = 10mm of Mitte, xshift=2cm]  {4.1};
\node (Verwaltung) [left = 10mm of Mitte, xshift=-2cm]  {4.2}; 
\coordinate [below = 0.5cm of EDV] (zoode);
\coordinate [below = 0.5cm of Verwaltung] (dire);
\node (Bau)        [below = of Verwaltung] {421};
\node (Logistik)   [below  = of Bau]        {4211};
\node (4212)   [below  = of Logistik]        {4212};
\node (4213)   [below  = of 4212]        {4213};
\node (Pflege)     [below = of EDV]        {411};
\node (Ausbildung) [right = of Pflege]     {412};
\node (413) [right = of Ausbildung]     {413};
\node (4121) [below = of Ausbildung]     {4121};
  \draw[line width=0.1cm, green!60!black]
(SWGDAM)    -- (Mitte) -- (Verwaltung)
% (EDV)   -- (Mitte) -- (Unten) -| (Logistik)
(EDV)   -- (Mitte)
 % (Unten) -| (Bau)
 % (Unten) -| (Pflege)
% (Unten) -| (Ausbildung);
(EDV)   -- (zoode)
(zoode) -| (Pflege)
(zoode)  -| (Ausbildung);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Can I make a general code for all the nodes through every node/.style? @runartrollet

Comment: what do you mean? you already have a general style for that, with green rectangles? do you want all of them changed to white circles instead? I thought it was only the white one. I think you should improve your original question and retract this as an accepted answer. Other people will give this question more focus then.

Comment: This picture is good. I just want to add a label to every node with the same shape you did for one of the nodes. I am not sure whether it could be possible through modifying the style.

Comment: ok, again, my suggestion is to modify your question, add more information about what you want to do, and retract this answer as an accepted answer.